# Can't create a Folder using BOX API v2.0

Tags: box-api

```
function post($url, $params, $headers) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
$parent_id = 0;
$name = 'examplefolder';
$params = array('name' => $name => json_encode(array('id' => $parent_id)));
$resp = post('https://api.box.com/2.0/folders', $params, array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE));
```

When this code executes I got this error in Json format

```
{"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"missing_parameter","name":"parent","message":"'parent' is required"},{"reason":"missing_parameter","name":"name","message":"'name' is required"}]},"help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Bad Request","request_id":"204107642652b93aceca050"}
```

Is there anything I'm missing?

Additional note.
I even tried to make the params a query string like this.

```
name=examplefolder&parent={"id":0}
```

and this gives me a different error

```
{"type":"error","status":400,"code":"bad_request","context_info":{"errors":[{"reason":"invalid_parameter","name":"entity-body","message":"Invalid value 'name=examplefolder&parent={\"id\":0}'. Entity body should be a correctly nested resource attribute name\/value pair"}]},"help_url":"http:\/\/developers.box.com\/docs\/#errors","message":"Bad Request","request_id":"154368831052b93bb027779"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally familiar with this language syntax, but it looks to me like the `parent` object is not declared in your POST body. You need to be sending this:

```
{"name":NAME, "parent":{"id":"0"}}
```

You might be able to accomplish that by changing your $params like so:

```
$params = array('name' => $name, 'parent' => json_encode(array('id' => $parent_id)));
```

Also, per the documentation the `$parent_id` should be serialized as a string, not as an integer.

Comment: Also to clarify, Box API expects Post Body to be JSON https://developers.box.com/docs/#api-basics so instead of sending the body as name=examplefolder it would be {"name": "examplefolder" } in the request body

Answer (score 0):

{"name":NAME, "parent":{"parent_id":"0"}}

This worked for me when I was working Angular 1 - angular file upload module.

However it is different with angular2, still working on..

```
vm.uploader.onBeforeUploadItem = function (item) {
  if (!vm.parentFolderId || item.isVersionUpload) return;
  item.headers = { Authorization: 'Bearer ' + vm.userToken };
  item.formData = {
    name: item.file.name,
    parent: {
      parent_id: vm.parentFolderId
    }
  };
}
```